# Overwriting dlls in MEF

Tags: .net, mef

Right now, I'm trying to separate out a set of constantly changing classes into their own dll and dynamically load them using MEF. My problem is that whenever I try and overwrite the dll while the app is running, it says it's in use.

Is there anyway to configure MEF to let me overwrite the dll and pick up the changes while the app is still running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an MEF issue - it is your appdomain standard setup that locks the DLL's touched. Check http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/26164-reflection-assembly-loadfile-locks-file.html for a similar issue not involveind MEF.

Basically, do not run on the dll's, make a copy first and work on the copy ;)

Check http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/07/29/4146.aspx for the AppDomain ShadowCopy mechanism ;)

Comment: I'm confused here - are you saying MEF is the wrong tool for a situation described in the ShadowCopy link?  (I'm doing a windows service).  I thought it was developed precisely so you can replace dll's without stopping an application.

Comment: MEF - after identification - loads assemblies using the standard setup of the AppDomain. If the AppDomain is not configured to use shadow copy, it will not use shadow copy.

Answer (score 2):

I *suspect* it will work if you completely unload any `AppDomain` which currently references the DLL.