# Releasing a file that is loaded in Managed Extensibility Framework ( MEF )

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I have ventured into the world of MEF for the first time and I am trying to figure out if it'll do what I am trying to accomplish.  I am writing a windows service that is needed to call a few DLLs that are going to contain some business logic and then work with the datalayer.  It was requested that these DLLs be "hotswappable" when the the windows service is running.  I was hoping MEF can help me with this.  I am attempting to test this out with a console application:

```
        bool bFlag = true;

        while(bFlag) {

            DirectoryCatalog catalog;
            CompositionContainer container;

            catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@"C:\serviceTest");
            container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            try {

                var x = container.GetExport<IAlgorithm>();

                var y = x.Value.Process("");

                foreach(var z in y.Messages) {
                    Console.WriteLine(z.Message);
                }

            } catch(Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("error"); }

            container.ReleaseExports(container.GetExports<IAlgorithm>());

            var o = Console.ReadLine();

            if(o.Trim() != string.Empty) {
                bFlag = false;
            }
        }
```

So now with that application running I drop the DLL that implements IAlgorithm into the folder and Process returns the messages I am using in the DLL. I then update that dll to return a different message and try to replace the previously used one, but I cannot. The file is locked by the application.    Is there a way around this?

I've tried a few different ways to go about this code and my latest is trying container.ReleaseExports.  I have tried disposing everything as well and get the same result. Am I doing something wrong, am I missing something, or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a duplicate post. Please take a look at this post. [overwriting-dlls-in-mef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745093/overwriting-dlls-in-mef)

"This is not an MEF issue - it is your appdomain standard setup that locks the DLL's touched."

Comment: Awesome, that does seem to point me in the right direction. I couldn't seem to find a related article on SO but it could have been from the text I was using.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I know MEF can cause some strange exceptions. Good luck.